# Using attachment caching in Axis2 SAAJ

Tags: java, apache-axis, mtom, saaj

I am upgrading an existing SOAP stack (both client and server side) inside an application to support binary content through the use of SOAP Attachments (SwA or MTOM).
The existing code base leverages the SAAJ extensively, and uses the Axis2 (1.5.6 as it is) implementation. (Other parts of the application already use Axis2 so it seems reasonable to stick to it).

When building a SOAPMessage through the SAAJ API (adding Nodes, Elements, SOAPAttachments instances...) everything works just fine. The serialized SOAPMessage is indeed a proper xop/mtom message.

My problem arises when parsing such a Message as an InputStream through Axis2's MessageFactory (no we do not use an AxisServlet/Endpoint, we sometimes parse raw streams directly).
It works (I get back a functionnaly equivalent SOAPMessage instance), but I would like Axis2 to use (axiom's underlying) attachment caching feature so as not to have attachments read into main memory, and I can't make this happen.

From my understanding of Axis2's implementation in axis-saaj.jar it seems the SOAPMessageImpl is hard coded to instanciate an Axiom Attachments instance without the caching feature enabled and it looks like there is no configurable way (axis conf file, system property, proprietary extension of the messagefactory, whatever...) to change this behavior.

Am I missing something ? Isn't there a way to use axis-saaj with attachment caching (or any other way to get from an InputStream to a SOAPMessage instance) ?
There is virtually no documentation on axis2-saaj that I can find, and the Axis User ML has stayed silent about this so far.

Thanks!